# How do I disable this Div Tag?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have installed a Wordpress plugin which as default adds a countdown clock to a single product page.

However it doesn't display correctly on the page.

I'd like the countdown clock to display underneath the "Add To Cart" button but I'm unsure what to edit.

I've already tried to disable the countdown clock by adding code to my custom css section within my theme.

```
.rtg-time {
  display: none;
}
```

I thought it would disable the countdown clock but it doesn't do anything.

Here's a link to the product page in question: https://www.prizejunkie.co.uk/product/paul-smith/

Comment: to start with, the div with the countdown clock isn't called .rtg-time, it's #time-remaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have elements using `float` to align the 'Quantity' and 'Buy Tickets' side by side. As pointed out in the comments by Rachel, the item you need to edit is called `#time-remaining`.

To put the countdown clock under these elements, just clear the float so that the element is told it is not allowed to `float` (align side by side). If you do it like this, you will also need to clear the `p` tag for the 'end' messaging.

```
#end{
  clear:left
}
```

Change this:

```
#time-remaining {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
    margin-top: 10px;
    clear: left;
}
```